# I want to send email verification to another account in firebase that is not used for sign up of account

Tags: java, android, firebase, email-verification

I have 3 fields in my registration activity.

Username Email and Password.

So the account will be created with the Username which will show up on the authentication page but I want to send the email to the Email field but how do I send it to the email specified in the editTextEmail. Here is the code I used.

```
package net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.AbstractCollection;

public class ChildSignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText editTextEmail,editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void registerUser (){
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            editTextEmail.setError(("Please enter a valid email"));
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Your password must be at least 6 characters");
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // send user verification link using firebase

                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChildSignUpActivity.this, "Verification Email Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                        }
                    });



                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Register Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonSignUp:
                registerUser();
                break;

            case R.id.textViewLogin:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

So I want the field called email to get the verification email could anyone offer a solution?

Comment: can you expain your Question means you want to send a verification email to the email id of user or you want to get the email id with this username ? 
As per the answer given by @fatalcoder524  It seems you are trying to get the email id of user ..

Comment: I want to send a verification email to the user which they will give and will be stored in the Firebase real time database but I want the verification of email to take place but I want the user to be able to login with username as there is a reason to it https://stackoverflow.com/users/12248003/n-balgopal-patro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a document in firestore with document name as **username** and field **email**.

> **profiles**
>
> - fatalcoder524 //username
>
>   1. email: test@test.com  //email to validate
>   2. dob: 12/12/12 //other details

First check if the username is present in firestore.

- If exists, use the email in firestore and password by user to validate.
- If not, ask user to signup.

**Sample Code: (Signup)**

```java
String email; //user input
String username; //user input
String password; //user input

Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("email", email);   // data to add to firestore

db.collection("profiles").document(username) //username is set as firestore document name, profiles is the collection name
        .set(user)  //Store the email in above document.
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) // If data is added successfully
            {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) // create account
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

            }
        });
```

**Sample Code: (Signin)**

```java
String username;  //get username from user
String password; //get password from user
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("profiles").document(username); //get doc reference
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) // if username is present
            { 
                String email=document.getData().email; //get email from document
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) //signin with email
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) // if password and email id matches
                {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                //add code (user not found/registered) 
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

**Modification of your code:**

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private void registerUser (){
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            editTextEmail.setError(("Please enter a valid email"));
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Your password must be at least 6 characters");
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("email", email);

        db.collection("profiles").document(username) //username is set as firestore document name, profiles is the collection name
        .set(user)  //Store the email in above document.
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) // If data is added successfully
            {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // send user verification link using firebase

                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChildSignUpActivity.this, "Verification Email Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                        }
                    });



                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Register Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11783181/fatalcoder524 Ok so what code do I add in the project within android studio. Could you be a bit more specific regarding how to make the document in Firestone. I am new to this stuff as I am a java coder and I haven’t done it in a while.

Comment: So what code do I add in order for me to log in with the username and validate the email? Both for Firebase and in android studio? Some clarification would be great thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/11783181/fatalcoder524

Comment: This code is designed from the docs. Not exactly specific and might need more changes, but this is the basic structure. *Accept* and *Upvote* if helped. Thank you. @user13874345

Comment: I actually want to sign in with username so how would I do that? @fatalcoder524 stackoverflow.com/users/11783181/fatalcoder524

Comment: That's what I did in the code above... user enters username and password. email is taken from the database. that way u can implement forgot password and verify email. @user13874345

Comment: stackoverflow.com/users/11783181/fatalcoder524 For the firestore document I am creating the field email but what do I put for the value section? @fatalcoder524

Comment: I don't understand how to create the document? do I add in test@test.com as the string value? @fatalcoder524

Comment: NO, that is an example of how data is stored in firestore.

Comment: I will add more comments to the code for you to understand

Comment: there is an error when I use the code you wrote. One the city.put is said that it is not a valid token. same for the db.collection

Comment: it says that it cannot resolve the symbol city and db so what do I do? could I contact you any other way

Comment: See docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart for db reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219267/discussion-between-fatalcoder524-and-user13874345).

Comment: can we continue our discussion in the chat

Answer (score 1):

"So the account will be created with the Username which will show up on the authentication page." Do you want the username to appear on the authentication page in your firebase console. I don't think that can be done or why it should be done. The right way would be to create user with email and password and then update the user's profile with the username he wants like this-

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Later, if you need the username, you can access it using-

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        String name = profile.getDisplayName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to log in using the username because the parent to the child will have the email. The email field is just for the parent to verify the account and I will use it to send other emails. So I want to use the username to log in

Comment: Then you will have to do it the using the way @fatalcoder524 has sugguested.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix my problem is the first use the firestore to save the user data for username then use the tricks in the fatal coders post then that should fix it and let you sign in.